# NavigationBar layer gradient not working well

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am adding gradient to navigation Bar' layer and it is working fine. 
Issue arrive when I push another view Controller and pop view Controller. Parent view Controller has right Bar Button Item whose color dims when I pop View Controller. 
My code is

```
CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
navFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:[AddGradient addGradientToNavigationBar:navFrame] atIndex:0];
```

code for addGradientToNavigationBar is

```
+ (CAGradientLayer*)addGradientToNavigationBar:(CGRect)navRect {

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = navRect;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor],
                   (id)[[XAppDelegate getColor] CGColor], nil];

    return gradient;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. 
I was tying to add gradient layer to navigation bar with the UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent style for glass effect. After searching the web and a lot of experiments I have not found the right solution for that problem. Finally I've came up with following work around:

```
    CAGradientLayer *yourGradient = ...
```

// Need two additional layers to mimic UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent style

```
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);


    NSMutableArray *cgColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [cgColors addObject:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0
                                     green:0.0
                                      blue:0.0
                                     alpha:0.2] CGColor]];
    [cgColors addObject:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0
                                     green:0.0
                                      blue:0.0
                                     alpha:0.6] CGColor]];
    [cgColors addObject:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0
                                     green:0.0
                                      blue:0.0
                                     alpha:0.5] CGColor]];

    gradient.colors = cgColors;

    CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];

    _layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 22, 320, 22);

    _layer.backgroundColor =[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0
                                             green:0.0
                                              blue:0.0
                                             alpha:0.2] CGColor];
```

// This is needed for navigation bar buttons

```
    [rootController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

// Adding layers to the first sublayer of the navigation bar layer

```
    [[[rootController.navigationBar.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] insertSublayer:yourGradient atIndex:0];
```

// After adding the gradient layer, the UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent style effect disappears

// from the bar (but not from the buttons)

// So the following is needed to mimic it

```
    [[[rootController.navigationBar.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:1];

    [[[rootController.navigationBar.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] insertSublayer:layer atIndex:2];
```

you may also want to add some borders to your layer as the borders seems to disappear.